# Rails Apartment: Adding www. redirects to public tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm having a problem with creating a multi-tenancy app with Ruby on Rails, using the apartment gem.  The problem is that whenever I add www. to the start of my web URL, it takes me back to the public tenant.  I am using Heroku and google domains to add a wildcard subdomain.   Example:  tenant1.website.com works.  www.tenant1.website.com  takes me to the public tenant. Fixes?

```
# You can have Apartment route to the appropriate Tenant by adding some Rack middleware.
# Apartment can support many different "Elevators" that can take care of this routing to your data.
# Require whichever Elevator you're using below or none if you have a custom one.
#
# require 'apartment/elevators/generic'
# require 'apartment/elevators/domain'
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'
# require 'apartment/elevators/first_subdomain'
# require 'apartment/elevators/host'

#
# Apartment Configuration
#
Apartment.configure do |config|

  Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']

  # Add any models that you do not want to be multi-tenanted, but remain in the global (public) namespace.
  # A typical example would be a Customer or Tenant model that stores each Tenant's information.
  #
   config.excluded_models = %w{ User }

  # In order to migrate all of your Tenants you need to provide a list of Tenant names to Apartment.
  # You can make this dynamic by providing a Proc object to be called on migrations.
  # This object should yield either:
  # - an array of strings representing each Tenant name.
  # - a hash which keys are tenant names, and values custom db config (must contain all key/values required in database.yml)
  #
  # config.tenant_names = lambda{ Customer.pluck(:tenant_name) }
  # config.tenant_names = ['tenant1', 'tenant2']
  # config.tenant_names = {
  #   'tenant1' => {
  #     adapter: 'postgresql',
  #     host: 'some_server',
  #     port: 5555,
  #     database: 'postgres' # this is not the name of the tenant's db
  #                          # but the name of the database to connect to before creating the tenant's db
  #                          # mandatory in postgresql
  #   },
  #   'tenant2' => {
  #     adapter:  'postgresql',
  #     database: 'postgres' # this is not the name of the tenant's db
  #                          # but the name of the database to connect to before creating the tenant's db
  #                          # mandatory in postgresql
  #   }
  # }
  # config.tenant_names = lambda do
  #   Tenant.all.each_with_object({}) do |tenant, hash|
  #     hash[tenant.name] = tenant.db_configuration
  #   end
  # end
  #
  config.tenant_names = lambda { User.pluck :subdomain }

  # PostgreSQL:
  #   Specifies whether to use PostgreSQL schemas or create a new database per Tenant.
  #
  # MySQL:
  #   Specifies whether to switch databases by using `use` statement or re-establish connection.
  #
  # The default behaviour is true.
  #
  # config.use_schemas = true

  #
  # ==> PostgreSQL only options

  # Apartment can be forced to use raw SQL dumps instead of schema.rb for creating new schemas.
  # Use this when you are using some extra features in PostgreSQL that can't be represented in
  # schema.rb, like materialized views etc. (only applies with use_schemas set to true).
  # (Note: this option doesn't use db/structure.sql, it creates SQL dump by executing pg_dump)
  #
  # config.use_sql = false

  # There are cases where you might want some schemas to always be in your search_path
  # e.g when using a PostgreSQL extension like hstore.
  # Any schemas added here will be available along with your selected Tenant.
  #
  # config.persistent_schemas = %w{ hstore }

  # <== PostgreSQL only options
  #

  # By default, and only when not using PostgreSQL schemas, Apartment will prepend the environment
  # to the tenant name to ensure there is no conflict between your environments.
  # This is mainly for the benefit of your development and test environments.
  # Uncomment the line below if you want to disable this behaviour in production.
  #
  # config.prepend_environment = !Rails.env.production?

  # When using PostgreSQL schemas, the database dump will be namespaced, and
  # apartment will substitute the default namespace (usually public) with the
  # name of the new tenant when creating a new tenant. Some items must maintain
  # a reference to the default namespace (ie public) - for instance, a default
  # uuid generation. Uncomment the line below to create a list of namespaced
  # items in the schema dump that should *not* have their namespace replaced by
  # the new tenant
  #
  # config.pg_excluded_names = ["uuid_generate_v4"]
end

# Setup a custom Tenant switching middleware. The Proc should return the name of the Tenant that
# you want to switch to.
# Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Generic, lambda { |request|
#   request.host.split('.').first
# }

# Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Domain
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
# Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::FirstSubdomain
# Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Host
```

Let me know if there's any other relevant code I need to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the subdomain elevator only grabs the first host segment. Relevant code is [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/blob/development/lib/apartment/elevators/subdomain.rb):

```
# Only care about the first subdomain for the database name
def subdomain(host)
  subdomains(host).first
end
```

This is also noted in the [documentation](https://github.com/influitive/apartment):

> This functions much in the same way as the Subdomain elevator. NOTE: in fact, at the time of this writing, the Subdomain and FirstSubdomain elevators both use the first subdomain ([#339](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/339#issuecomment-235578610)). If you need to switch on larger parts of a Subdomain, consider using a Custom Elevator.

For a custom elevator, you can work off the [subdomain elevator](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/blob/development/lib/apartment/elevators/subdomain.rb) and override the subdomain method to pick the last subdomain instead of the first:

```
# lib/last_subdomain_elevator.rb
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'
class LastSubdomainElevator < Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain

  protected

  # Only care about the last subdomain for the database name
  def subdomain(host)
    subdomains(host).last
    ## Alternatively, use all segments of the subdomain
    # subdomains(host).join(".")
  end
end
```

Load the custom elevator in your apartment config:

```
# config/initializers/apartment.rb
require_relative "../../lib/last_subdomain_elevator"

Apartment.configure do |config| 
  ....
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use LastSubdomainElevator
```

Comment: I'm going to add for future users:  When you make a custom elevator like this, I had to go to the apartment gem's code and extract the subdomain exclude code because the default method wasn't working, and i had to put it in my custom elevator.